# Sample proportion confidence interval estimates using logit

Tags: math, statistics, probability, intervals

This seems like a problem that has an accepted, statistically and mathematically sound answer, but I can't seem to find it.

When estimating confidence intervals from sample proportions, I generally use the normal approximation technique described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Normal_approximation_interval

However, this fails spectacularly for proportions where my sample is close to 0 or 1, notably having symmetrical distribution which causes it to go above 1 or below 0. Generally, since proportion estimates "behave better" when modeled using a logit, I assume there is some way to apply a logit transform to the confidence intervals which would result in an asymmetric confidence interval that would never cross 0 or 1.

However, instead of trying to hack together my own technique with freshman calculus and MBA statistics as my highest formal mathematical training, I have been searching the web to see if such a technique has already been described by someone more qualified.

Is anyone aware of a way to do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward derivation via the usual change of variables formula shows that y = logit(x) where x has a beta distribution (the posterior distribution for the binomial proportion assuming a beta prior), has a distribution with pdf `(exp(y)^a)/((1 + exp(y))^(a + b))/beta(a, b)` where `beta(a, b) = gamma(a)*gamma(b)/gamma(a + b)`.

That pdf has a somewhat Gaussian-like shape, but it's less symmetrical the more different a and b are. It probably has a name, although I don't recognize it.

It's not clear that taking y = logit(x) here is helpful. For several other approaches, see: [Binomial proportion confidence interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval)

Statistics problems should probably go to stats.stackexchange.com.